# Extrapolating diffs with python

Tags: python, typeerror, difflib

i'm using a library to extrapolate the diffs between two json files. My code loads them into dictionaries and then uses [datadiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datadiff/1.1.4) to get the difference between the two data structure. The problem is that i want to process further the output of:

```
datadiff.diff
```

to make an html of the diffs found in the two data structures. In order to do it i have to process the output of the command and divide it in lines. Then if the lines begins with + i know that the output have to be referred to the second file compared, if the lines begins with - then i have to attribute it to the first file.
Mycode:

```
    out = datadiff.diff(t[0].get("key"),t[1].get("key"))
    for line in out:
        if str(line).startswith("+"):
            f.write(str(line)+"<br/>")
        if str(line).startswith("-"):
            f.write(str(line)+"<br/>")
```

This code gices me a TypeError:

```
for line in out:
TypeError: 'DataDiff' object is not iterable
```

I can transform the whole datadiff.diff in a string but then i have to split it somehow to get all the lines as it get translated to a single line string:

```
         out = str(datadiff.diff(t[0].get("key"),t[1].get("key")))+"<br/>"
```

Datadiff Output:

```
diff in key:
--- a
+++ b
[
@@ -0,1 +0,1 @@
-{u'origin': u'NORMAL', u'score': 100, u'type': u'FEELINGS', u'name': u'sentiment negativo', u'children': [u'reato']},
 {u'origin': u'NORMAL', u'score': 100, u'type': u'FEELINGS', u'name': u'sentiment neg', u'children': [u'reato']},
+{u'origin': u'NORMAL', u'score': 50, u'type': u'FEELINGS', u'name': u'sentiment negativo', u'children': [u'reato']},
]
```

Comment: You should post the `datadiff.diff()` results as we have no idea what it looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the [source for the `DataDiff.stringify()` method](http://sourceforge.net/p/datadiff/code/ci/master/tree/datadiff/__init__.py#l127), where you can see how the output is generated from the `.diffs` list:

```
def output(ddiff, f, depth=0):
    for change, items in out.diffs:
        if change in ('insert', 'delete'):
            prefix = '-' if change == 'delete' else '+'
            for line in items:
                f.write('{}{}{}<br/>'.format(prefix, depth * ' ', line))
        elif change == 'datadiff':
            output(items, f, depth + 1)
            f.write(',')

output(out, f)
```

If you want to work with just the string output, then use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to get separate lines again:

```
for line in str(out).splitlines():
    # etc.
```

Comment: Very helpful this `splitlines()` method. Ty